# You must provide a Stripe Element or a valid token type to create a Token

Tags: stripe-payments

let stripe = Stripe("pk_XXXXXX");
        let card = await stripe.createToken({
          card: "4242424242424242",
          exp_month: "02",
          expDate: "21",
          cvc: "999",
          name: "Billy Joe"
        });

Comment: You should use Elements or Checkout to create card tokens instead, as handling raw credit card numbers this way [places you in PCI scope](https://stripe.com/docs/security#validating-pci-compliance). Or use one of the provided [test tokens](https://stripe.com/docs/testing#cards) e.g. 4242 can also be referred to as `tok_visa` for usage with the API.